# Svn copy directories

Tags: svn

It happens to me to modify or generate files or entire directory trees outside a versioned directory.

The problem is that whenever I copy back the tree to the svn-versioned directory (for example with Finder in MacOSX), .svn directories get overridden and Subversion starts complaining. What's a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't you use Export to copy the code outside of the versioned directory? That way, .svn directories will not go with the files.

Answer (score 1):

Files can be modified outside the versioned directory and copied back later. However, versioned directories contain hidden data about the files it contains and overwriting a directory  is not going to work.

I don't see a good reason to work outside the versioned directory and as a conclusion I encourage you to read the SVN book, especially the "move" section : http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re18.html

Comment: there are indeed lots of situation where don't working on a versioned directory is used. i rece files from non-technical partners in any number of different formats and structures and i need to archive them. i have processes generating files on different servers and i need to analyze, merge, and preserve them and so on.

Comment: I see. Maybe SVN is not what you need (too technical for non techies). Automatizing the retrieval, analysis, merging and committing of files would certainly improve your life as well. Otherwise, Dmitry's answer could help you ; I didn't know about the 1.7 feature he mentions.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problem is using or a 3-URL-merge

**svn_load_dirs.pl**

See these question which have an extremly similar topic:

- [best way to replace a whole directory tree in subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192915/best-way-to-replace-a-whole-directory-tree-in-subversion) (about svn_load_dirs.pl)
- [are there any  alternatives to svn_load_dirs.pl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322268/are-there-any-alternatives-to-svn-load-dirs-pl) (3-URL-merge)

**Note:** Simply copying directories over the new version will *NOT* delete files which are removed in the current version. These files will be *unchanged* which is at least confusing, most of the time an annoyance and sometimes even an error

Answer (score 0):

Use some serious utility (e.g. on Windows I use [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/), I hope there exist such utilities for MAC). Such tools have options that allow you to specify what you want to copy and what to skip. If push comes to shove - write a simple shell script that copies everything, but .svn directory.

Also, SVN 1.7 working copy format has .svn only at the top level of your working copy under regular circumstances. So switching to 1.7 may somewhat ease your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the svn client v1.7 and update the working copy to the 1.7 format. It keeps all metadata in a single subfolder of the woking copy root folder. Hope, it helps with your problem.

[Subversion 1.7 Working Copy Metadata Storage Improvements](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-ng)